# Why is my NextJS site returning a 304 for a non-conditional request?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a NextJS 13.5.6 website, built using the app router pattern. When using dynamic rendering (either through forcing it with `export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'` or the absence of `generateStaticParams`) pages are rendered and returned normally, but with a cache-control that prevents caching.

I want to make use of a caching proxy, so I added the `generateStaticParams` method that returns an empty array. This causes the build phase to identify this route as SSG (HTML+JSON) rather than dynamic, and correctly sets the max-age and cache-control to appropriate values as defined by the fetch cache parameters.

```
Route (app)                              Size     First Load JS
┌ ○ /_not-found                          0 B                0 B
├ ● /[[...slug]]                         5.04 kB         125 kB
├ λ /api/meilisearch/global              0 B                0 B
├ ○ /blog                                4.24 kB         108 kB
├ λ /blog/[category]                     185 B          92.6 kB
├ λ /blog/[category]/[slug]              10.4 kB        95.9 kB
└ ○ /search                              2.39 kB        82.8 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all            80.4 kB
  ├ chunks/472-34dba180b7787ade.js       27.5 kB
  ├ chunks/fd9d1056-5e9401db64e8ca2f.js  50.9 kB
  ├ chunks/main-app-8dbd315aba1c0e27.js  231 B
  └ chunks/webpack-e8bed7bb2e236007.js   1.79 kB


ƒ Middleware                             25.6 kB

λ  (Server)  server-side renders at runtime (uses getInitialProps or getServerSideProps)
○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)
●  (SSG)     automatically generated as static HTML + JSON (uses getStaticProps)
```

However, I am seeing intermittent non-compliant HTTP responses. While sometimes a 200 is returned, other times I get a 304 response:

```
$ curl -vv localhost:3000
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:3000...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 3000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:3000
> User-Agent: curl/7.81.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
< Vary: RSC, Next-Router-State-Tree, Next-Router-Prefetch, Next-Url, Accept-Encoding
< x-nextjs-cache: STALE
< X-Powered-By: Next.js
< ETag: "csmmdl1leryx7"
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 45261
< Date: Fri, 02 Feb 2024 17:27:52 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=5
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

As the original request from cURL was not conditional, the server should not return a 304 response. Why is the backend returning this response, and how can I prevent it?